# Access the web server from different devices - ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: cpanel, vps, whm

When I access the web server (`https //: xxx.com`) from different devices - cellphone, tablet and pc I get the error `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`, all the devices are on the same ip address. (when each device has a different ip address everything works ok).

Only the last device can access the web with the other error message `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

It is a vps server that has a wmh panel.

this creates a problem for me, when multiple computers from the office need to access an application located on the server, only one can work.

Comment: Is it using CSF firewall?

Comment: yes, a CSF firewall is installed, but the same error occurs when it is on and off.

Comment: Have you whitelisted the IP? Is it getting blocked?  Have you checked the CSF log?

Comment: ip not blocked, nothing in CSF log,

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the apache configuration.

Try this IN WHM:
Edit "Global configuration" in Home >> Service Configuration >> Apache Configuration >> Global configuration

Set this config:

- Start Servers: 100
- Minimum Spare Server: 100
- Server limit: 600
- Max Request Workers: 1000

Save and click on the button "Rebuild configuration and Restar apache"

Comment: The problem is,
if, for example, multiple computers running the same operating system can access the server, however, if one of them uses a Mac, no one else can access the server, the others get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, the same thing happens if someone connects via cellphone or tablet.

Everyone uses the wiress network, the same ip, if different ip, everything works.

Comment: here's an example,
check out this page (https://www.brana-tours.hr/?l=en) from your pc and then try from your mobile phone, you should have the same ip .. and when you open the web on your mobile, your computer should an error occurs .. time_out.